# Which Siemens breakers are used for ITE Load Center?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I am replacing some faulty breakers and I am trying to locate the type of breakers that I can use.

I know that ITE was acquired by Siemens, so I am assuming they carry breakers that will fit. Plus, I would prefer using Siemens personally if possible. Here are some photos of the main panel and info sticker:
[image: Whole Panel]

[image: information sticker]

I need a few 15 and 20 amp breakers and also need a few GFCI in each.

Any assistance is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably don't *need* a few GFCI in each. GFCI can be installed at the first relevant receptacle, typically at a much lower price than in the breaker panel. More convenient reset too.

Comment: Could we get a closer, in-focus picture of the bottom 3 breakers on the right-hand side? They look a bit out of place. Could be correctly "classified" and listed replacement breakers, could be improper replacements. GFCI breakers will be annoying because you had a "no excess wire!" guy in this panel cutting the neutrals short. **and** we appear to have multiple neutrals under one screw several locations, which is Not OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a quick supplier search for EQ-P and EQ-T (and without drilling down to the level of verification some of our normal sparkies may yet bring to bear:)

GFCI - QF115 and QF120 (and others that you don't appear to need, since I don't see any MWBCs in the panel.)

AFCI - Q115AF and Q120AF (and others that you don't appear to need, since I don't see any MWBCs in the panel.)

Plain ol' breakers - Q115 and Q120 and Q230 and Q240 and Q250 (and a whole bunch of others.)

They are listed as ITE Gould/Siemens which I presume to mean Siemens made to fit ITE Gould Panels post-acquisition.

There are other sorts as well, but that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: That is correct -- ITE EQ-P is what became the current Siemens QP line.  Also, the OP needs to evict that alien BR breaker in the bottom right that snuck in somehow...

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you very much!

Comment: Just an update, I have cleaned up the panel and isntalled all new simens breakers and fixes the multiple neutrals under one lug issue. I really appreciate the help! Also, those bottom three breakers definitely shouldn't have been there.