# Siemens Replacement Parts to Refurbish old ITE EQ Load Center

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, repair, code-compliance

I am re-wiring some areas of my new home to install new outlets, receptacles, and replace some fun (by fun I mean terrifying & dangerous) wiring that was installed since the house was built in the 70s.

My main panel in the basement is an ITE EQ Load center and I am really looking for any current (or at least more recent) parts (or a current panel model number to look myself) that would be compatible to partly refurbish/clean up the panel. Sure, I could replace the whole panel, but I feel like I have a piece of living history and kinda want to preserve it while making it safe and neat if possible.

I already know that the ITE EQ-P breakers this panel references essentially evolved into the Siemens QP line (thanks to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/242034/which-siemens-breakers-are-used-for-ite-load-center)) and have already replaced all breakers.

Here's all the info I know:

ITE was purchased by Gould in 1976 and then Gould was purchased by Siemens in 1983. The panel is an ITE EQ Load Center with a model number of EQ28MBA.

**Details:**

- 120/240 Volt A.C.
- Single Phase
- 3 Wire
- Max rating of 150 Amps
- 150 Amps Main Breaker
- 28 Slots
- EQ-P or EQ-T breaker type (Siemens QP Line)
- Patent 3349292 (Click [Here](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3349292) to view Patent Documents)

[image: Panelboard, Breakers, Wiring, Cabinet (Inside)]

[image: Panel Cover Labels (Inside)]

[image: Load Center Specs, Wiring Information]

**UL Markings:**

- Panel Cover has UL Listed sticker with Issue #: H-858
  [image: Panel Cover UL Label]
- Panelboard has UL Listed sticker referencing CLASS-CTL and # AT331025
  [image: Panelboard UL Label]
- Cabinet Box has UL Listed sticker with Issue # M-25
  [image: Cabinet Box UL Label]

Any help in locating new compatible parts or an equivalent model number from Siemens would be fantastic!

Comment: Unfortunately, shopping and resource location questions are officially off-topic. What parts, in particular are you looking for/what issues are you looking to resolve in the panel? Specifying that might make for a better question.

Comment: Over on DIYChatroom we just had someone with a very similar looking panel, whose electrician was confident in being able to find a new(er)?) panel which uses the same "box size" and that the bus assembly could be swapped out of it.  The bus assembly is "the whole shebang" and the 4 screws that hold it in are right next to those tall spacer rods.  *Obviously, you need to have the meter pulled for that to happen, or have changed the meter to a meter-main which you can shut off*.

Comment: What are you trying to resolve by "refurbishing" the panel?

Comment: FYI: based upon the manufacturing date code ("J2072") visible in one of the photos, this panel has a 'born on' date of Sept. 20, 1972. Your panel is actually a pre-Gould purchase and therefore an I-T-E Imperial Corp. product.

Answer (score 1):

You've already done what is reasonable to do with the old panel, i.e. put in newer breakers within the same series.

If you really want to do a full rehab without tearing everything around it out, Eaton makes retrofit kits that replace all the guts of the panel, allowing you to use all modern CH or BR breakers including AFCI, CAFCI, GFCI, surge protectors, and similar. This can be a great option for some very specific circumstances. I don't think it's called for here, but if you want to go that way, it's doable.